# How to join two tables by using the first relevant date?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I would like to join to two tables using the date as the link, however, I do not want an exact match. The first table has more dates than the second one so I want the match to be dates from the second table to 'closest' date.

Example

Table 1:

```
Date1
2016-06-01
2016-06-02
2016-06-03
2016-06-04
2016-06-05
2016-06-06
2016-06-07
```

Table 2:

```
Date2
2016-06-01
2016-06-05
2016-06-07
```

Joined Table

```
Date1         Date2
2016-06-01    2016-06-01
2016-06-02    2016-06-01
2016-06-03    2016-06-01
2016-06-04    2016-06-01
2016-06-05    2016-06-05
2016-06-06    2016-06-05
2016-06-07    2016-06-07
```

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks,

SR

Comment: `SQL-Server` or `MySQL` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySql you can use a *correlated* subquery:

```
SELECT Date1, (SELECT Date2
               FROM Table2
               WHERE Date2 <= t1.Date1
               ORDER BY Date2 DESC LIMIT 1) AS Date2
FROM table1 AS t1
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b581b/1)

In SQL Server you can use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT t1.Date1, t2.Date2
FROM table1 AS t1
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT TOP 1 Date2
   FROM table2
   WHERE Date2 <= t1.Date1 
   ORDER BY Date2 DESC) AS t2
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using SQL Server. It is similar to Giorgos Betsos post

```
Declare @Table1 Table(Date1 date)
Insert into @Table1 values
('2016-06-01')
,('2016-06-02')
,('2016-06-03')
,('2016-06-04')
,('2016-06-05')
,('2016-06-06')
,('2016-06-07')

Declare @Table2 Table(Date2 date)
Insert into @Table2 values

('2016-06-01')
,('2016-06-05')
,('2016-06-07')

SELECT Date1, (SELECT top 1 Date2
               FROM @Table2
               WHERE Date2 <= t1.Date1
               order by Date2 desc) AS Date2
FROM @table1 AS t1
```

Comment: Thanks for the creating the example. It was very helpful in confirming the query